# Remove and recreate custom option programatically on product before save event

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, custom-options, option

I m creating a custom option programmatically using observer with the `catalog_product_save_before` event.The custom option was created successfully on product save. but the problem is whenever the product saves a second time it will create the same option on every save action.So I want to remove all the options first before save and recreate all the options on save. My observer code for creating custom option is as below

```
public function createMyCustomOption(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    //Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')->unsetOptions();
    $this->saveProductTabData($observer);
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $globlaOptions = unserialize(Mage::getStoreConfig("toursection/tourgroup/product_option"));
    $globlaOptionsArray = array();
    foreach ($globlaOptions as $key=>$value){
        $item['optiontitle'] = $value['optiontitle'];
        $item['optionprice'] = $value['optionprice'];
        $globlaOptionsArray[] = $item;
    }
    //print_r($globlaOptionsArray);
   
    //print_r($options);exit;
    
        $options = $product->getProductOptions();
    echo '<pre>';
    
      print_r($options);exit;
        /*if ($options) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                if ($option['title'] == 'Adult' || $option['title'] == 'Child') {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }*/
        
        $noOfAdult         = Mage::getStoreConfig("toursection/tourgroup/noofadult");
        $noOfchild         = Mage::getStoreConfig("toursection/tourgroup/nofochild");
        $adultPrice    = $product->getAdultOurprice();
        $childPrice    = $product->getChildOurprice();
        if(!$product_id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id')){
                $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $product_entity_table = $productModel->getResource()->getEntityTable();    
                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
                $result = $connection->showTableStatus($product_entity_table);
                $product_id = $result['Auto_increment'];
            }
        $optionModel = Mage::getModel('touroptions/touroptions')->load($product_id,'product_id');
        $tourOptionArray = unserialize($optionModel->getTouroptions());
        print_r($tourOptionArray);
        $optionsTitle = array('Adult','Child');
        $optionsPrice = array($adultPrice,$childPrice);
        $noOfOption = array(
            $noOfAdult,
            $noOfchild
        );
        $optionsSku = array(NULL,NULL);
        $isRequired    = array(
            1
        );
        $typeArray = array(
        'drop_down',
        'drop_down'
        );
        $inc = 0;
        foreach($globlaOptionsArray as $title){
            if(!in_array($title['optiontitle'],$tourOptionArray)){
                continue;
            }
            $optionsTitle[]=$title['optiontitle'];
            $optionsPrice[]=$title['optionprice'];
            $noOfOption[] = '1';
            $optionsSku[] = $tourOptionArray['optionsku'][$inc];
            $isRequired[] = 0;
            $typeArray[] = 'checkbox';
            $inc++;
            
        }
        
      
        $optionsArray  = $this->getOptions($optionsTitle, $typeArray, $noOfOption, $optionsPrice, $isRequired , $optionsSku);
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($optionsArray);exit;
        try {
            $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
            foreach ($optionsArray as $option) {
                $product->getOptionInstance()->addOption($option);
            }
            $product->setHasOptions(true);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::Log($e->getMessage());
        }
       
    
    
}
protected function getOptions($optionsTitle = '', $typeArray = '', $noOfOption, $optionsPrice, $isRequired, $optionsSku)
{
    
    if (is_array($optionsTitle)) {
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($optionsTitle as $ttl) {
            $option[$j]               = array();
            $optionvalue              = array();
            $option[$j]['title']      = $ttl;
            $option[$j]['type']       = $typeArray[$j];
            $option[$j]['is_require'] = $isRequired[$j];
            $option[$j]['sort_order'] = $j;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $noOfOption[$j]; $i++) {
                $optionvalue[$i]['title']      = $i;
                $optionvalue[$i]['price']      = $i * $optionsPrice[$j];
                $optionvalue[$i]['price_type'] = 'fixed';
                $optionvalue[$i]['sku']        = $optionsSku[$j];
                $optionvalue[$i]['sort_order'] = $i;
                
            }
            $option[$j]['values'] = $optionvalue;
            $j++;
        }
    } 
    return $option;
}
```

any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before adding your new options:

```
$oldOptions = $product->getOptionInstance()->getOptions();
foreach ($oldOptions as $option){
    $option->setIsDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it give me error  `Call to a member function setIsDelete() on a non-object`.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem, the answer from marius did not work for me. I got "Call to a member function setIsDelete() on a non-object" because $product->getOptionInstance()->getOptions() returns an array.

This is what worked for me:

```
$oldOptions = $product->getOptionInstance()->getOptions();
foreach ($oldOptions as $key => $option){
    if($option['title'] == "Custom Option Title") {
        $oldOptions[$key]['is_delete'] = 1;                 
        $product->getOptionInstance()->addOption($oldOptions[$key]);
    }
}
```

After deleting you can add your updated custom option with this code:

```
$newOption = array(
    'title' => "Custom Option Title",
    'type' => 'radio',
    'is_require' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 20,
    'values' => array(
        array(
            'title' => "Value 1 Title",
            'price' => 42.00,
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            'sku' => "",
            'sort_order' => '1'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => "Value 2 Title",
            'price' => 50,
            'price_type' => 'percent',
            'sku' => "",
            'sort_order' => '2'
        )
    )
);
$product->getOptionInstance()->addOption($newOption);
```